# Exclude multiple pages from restriction wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using this plugin called [Restricted Site Access](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/restricted-site-access/)

I want to exclude multiple pages from restriction.

I am using the below code but it only excludes single page.

```php
add_filter( 'restricted_site_access_is_restricted', 'my_rsa_feed_override', 10, 2 );
function my_rsa_feed_override( $is_restricted, $wp ) {
    // check query variables to see if this is the feed
    if ( ! empty( $wp->query_vars['pagename'] ) && $wp->query_vars['pagename'] == "guest-home" ) {
    $is_restricted = false;
    }
    return $is_restricted;
}
```

Comment: You want to exclude from restriction, archives and taxonomies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the code below, but you should fix it according to your needs by swapping the examples for the pages you want to disable:

```
add_filter( 'restricted_site_access_is_restricted', 'my_rsa_feed_override', 10, 2 );
function my_rsa_feed_override( $is_restricted, $wp ) {
    // check query variables to see if this is the feed
    if ( 
        ! empty( $wp->query_vars['pagename'] ) && $wp->query_vars['pagename'] == "guest-home" ||
        ! empty( $wp->query_vars['pagename'] ) && $wp->query_vars['pagename'] == "another-page" ||
        ! empty( $wp->query_vars['pagename'] ) && $wp->query_vars['pagename'] == "another-page-two" 
    ) {
        //should this be true no?
        $is_restricted = true;

       //$is_restricted = false;
    }
    return $is_restricted;
}
```